# Google Adsense Javascript code is blocking my other js scripts

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Why is "Google Adsense" Javascript code is blocking my js script?

My code works fine, but if I use the Google Adsense Javascript code, it stop working and if
I remove the "Google Adsense" Javascript code it starts working as it should...

**I have the following code**:

```
function start(){
    anc=document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(c=0;c<anc.length;c++) {
        anc[c].onclick=function() {
            if (this.firstChild.nodeValue == "SOMETHING")
            {
                Display_NTFF("Hello", "bye");
            }
            if (this.firstChild.nodeValue == "ReD")
            {
                Display_NTFF("HM", "NOOO!");
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload=function(){
    start();
}

function Display_NTFF(Name, About){
    document.getElementById('Name').firstChild.nodeValue=Name;
    document.getElementById('About').firstChild.nodeValue=About;
}
```

Comment: is there an error message? anything in the browser javascript console?

Comment: No, i don't now how to see that, because i'm using mac, and i can't see any error message. It just disappears, if i use the google code, but works if i remove it again...

Comment: I know the mac has some developer tool that should let you see the error. I am not a mac user, so I can't tell you where to look.

Comment: It so wird, i can't spot the error

Comment: The developer tool consol can't find andy warning, error or anything else..

Comment: Load the google script after dom ready instead of inline.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but your 'start' function has a pretty common name, making it more likely to collide with other libraries. Maybe google has a 'start' function too. Try changing your function to 'setupLinks' or something.

Answer (score 0):

Fault may rest on you `window.load`. This event will launch when all the assets in the page are loaded, including those in the ads. If ad providers timeout, you javascript event will not happen.